# Entity Framework 6 fails with MySql 6.8.3 not in GAC

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, dll

On my development system (VS2013 , MySql connector net 6.8.3 installed) my program works as expected. I'm using the NuGet packages `EntityFramework.6.1.0`, `MySql.ConnectorNET.Data.6.8.3.2` and `MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity.6.8.3.2`

On production I need to use the Entity Framework with MySql (e.g. 6.8.3) without installing it.

On my test system MySql connector net 6.2.3 is installed, the program should run with the MySql connector Net 6.8.3. The needed dll's (6.8.3 and EF6) are in the same directory as my c#-exe. I get the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d
```

The problem was already described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/23465559/3604523 but the solution to install mysql and pick it up from GAC is not a solution for me, because we need to deploy a mysql.data.dll independent from potentially installed mysql data providers.

(How) is this possible?

Here is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Test.csdl|res://*/Test.ssdl|res://*/Test.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=mytestserver;port=3306;User Id=root;password=;Persist Security Info=True;database=mytestdb&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you recently upgrade from EF5 to EF6? Please show use your Web.Config file

Comment: @Yorro Yes I upgraded to EF6. I added my app.config file.

Comment: @h.m.i.13 Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Tech I think my problem was, that I used the edmx and created classes from the old version. After I deleted the edmx and created the model and classes new from database with the T4 templates the problem was gone.